# I need help building the MVC without scaffolding. Twitter styled app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am trying to build a standard twitter styled app as a project. At the moment, I am just looking users being able to create posts/tweets. However, I am struggling as I don't want to scaffold as I want to understand the whole framework whilst working along.

1. Do I need to create a 'users' controller and model if I am going to use Devise? Do I need to create them seperately also?
2. When creating a posts/tweets 'model' and 'controller', I am confused what attributes I would have to add when creating these via terminal. I just want users to be able to post a status. Would it just be title:string, body:text? Would I add these attributes in the model or controller? :/

Sorry I am fairly new to rails and I understand these are basic questions for stackoverflow, but we all need to start somewhere. Sometimes I think I am overthinking it.

Take care,

Benjamin.

Comment: ""Would it just be title:string, body:text?"" there would need to be a foreign key user_id as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanna understand how framework works you should create each module separately, one after one. For `User` create separate model and controller, same for `Tweets` and so on.

And my suggestion, don't use Devise, make your project by yourself, in this case, you will know flow deeply.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend taking the free [RailsTutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org) by Michael Hartl. This tutorial takes you through the basis of Ruby in Rails in 8 chapters.

Specific to your questions:

- he's making a similar Twitter-app, so the tutorial guides you through each step;
- he's designing the User-authentication model himself, so no installation of Device needed.

Good luck!